# ¿Como hacer una petición POST con Guzzle enviando el body en formato JSON en Laravel?

Tags: laravel, json, guzzle

Estoy trabajando con Guzzle 6.5 conectandome a una Api y necesito hacer una petición POST enviando el body en formato JSON. Hasta ahora obtuve datos exitosamente con GET, pero al intentar con POST, tengo error. Tengo que enviar un header que tiene credenciales de autenticación, (que ya probé al usar get y funcionan ok) y un par de datos en el body en formato JSON.

Hasta ahora intente varias formas, sin éxito, agradecería enormemente me iluminen.

```
$headers = array( 
          "Authorization" => "Bearer ".$token->access_token,
          'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
          );

$body = array('codigo1' => '4');
```

//

```
$http2 = new Client();

forma1:
$res = $http2->request('POST', 'https://xxxxxxxxx.com',
  ['headers' => $headers,'json' => ['codigo1' => '4']]

forma2:
$res = $http2->request('POST', 'https://xxxxxxxxx.com',
  ['headers' => $headers,'form_params'=>['json' => ['codigo1' => '4']]]

forma3:
$res = $http2->request('POST', 'https://xxxxxxxxx.com',
  ['headers' => $headers,'body'=>['json' => ['codigo1' => '4']]]

forma4:
$body= json_encode($body);
$res = $http2->request('POST', 'https://xxxxxxxxx.com',
  ['headers' => $headers,'body'=>$body]

forma5:
$res = $http2->request('POST', 'https://xxxxxxxxx.com',
  ['headers' => $headers,'body'=> json_encode(['codigo1' => '4'])]
```

Comment: Laravel proporciona una API expresiva y mínima en torno al cliente Guzzle HTTP, lo que le permite realizar rápidamente solicitudes HTTP salientes para comunicarse con otras aplicaciones web. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/http-client

Comment: Agradeceria un ejemplo concreto de código, ya que no encuentro en ningun lado como enviar un header que contiene un token, mas un body como JSON. Incluso en la documentación de guzzle, no es claro el tema.

Comment: En principio, cuando dices "pero al intentar con POST, tengo error" usando Guzzle, ¿cuál es el error? Especialmente en el que muestras como "forma1". Luego, si quieres usar el HTTP Client de laravel, lo de la authentication con [bearer token](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/http-client#authentication) está en el la documentación que te pasé en el link, y [los datos se enviarán utilizando el tipo de contenido application/json por default](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/http-client#request-data).

Comment: La forma 1 me da error de autenticación en la api, creo que al usar 'json'=> esto añade un header propio, pisando el que yo declare que contiene el token de acceso. Voy a probar con la librería propia de laravel, como me estas indicando. En breve comento resultados. Gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Laravel estás usando? Esa clase está disponible a partir de la versión 7 (la actual). Igual [acabo de probar con guzzle](https://laravelplayground.com/#/snippets/97b6233e-7704-4793-a297-2d1608518ec9) y la forma 1 funciona bien, el header `Content-Type` no pisa al de `Authorization`, si te devuelve error de autenticación, es porque el token no es válido o la api a la que llamas tiene otro sistema de autenticar las solicitudes.

Comment: A la api estoy haciendo peticiones GET exitosamente, la autenticación funciona bien, me falla POST. Recién genere una instalación nueva de Laravel y de Guzzle, desde cero, para tener lo ultimo de librerías y dependencias. Estoy probando.

Comment: El problema es pasar un JSON, no un array común.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente pude hacer el request exitosamente enviando JSON de la siguiente manera. Esto coincide con la forma 1 de mi pregunta y lo que me insistió el usuario en sus comentarios bajo la pregunta. Se agrega al request http un array clásico que Guzzle transforma en json y envía a la api.

```
$mihttp = new Client();

$res = $mihttp->request('POST', 'https://xxxxxxx',
[
    'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json','Authorization'=> $token],
    'json' => ['codigo1' => '4','codigo2' => 'algo']
]
);

$estado=$res->getStatusCode();

if($estado=='200'){

  $resultado=$res->getBody()->getContents(); // recibe un json  
   
  $resultado = json_decode($resultado); //paso el json recibido a array  

  var_dump($resultado);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quiero agregar que Laravel tiene incorporado un cliente nativo con el cual puedes hacer peticiones HTTP.

En este caso para enviar un formulario con body, independiente del tipo de dato puedes usar la siguiente forma:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http; // Te permite realizar las peticiones

//Data original
$body = ['codigo1' => '4','codigo2' => 'algo'];
//Data formateada en json
$body = json_encode($body);
//Solicitud HTTP, luego de pasar el cuerpo, se debe especificar como segundo argumento el tipo de extensiones multipropósito. (MIME TYPES).
$res =  Http::withBody($body, 'application/json')->post($url);
```

Puedes revisar más a detalle [Laravel peticiones HTTP](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/http-client)